# SendKeys from WM_HOTKEY handler

Tags: delphi

Have AppActivate and SendKeys functions.

When use: AppActivate('*WordPad'); SendKeys('Test");
this works fine - application activated and text pasted

but then use it from WM_HOTKEY handler from the same program,
this is not worked.

Any ideas?

```
procedure wm_hotkeyhandler(var Msg: TWMHotkey); message WM_HOTKEY;
...
procedure TFormMain.wm_hotkeyhandler(var Msg: TWMHotkey);
var
  Pt: TPoint;
begin
  inherited;
  if (Msg.HotKey = HotKeyId_L) then SendKeys('Test'); // not pasted to active app
  if (Msg.HotKey = HotKeyId_M) then begin 
  // invoke context menu and paste text after click to menu item, works fine
                                      GetCursorPos(Pt);
                                      popPaste.Popup(Pt.x, Pt.y);
                                    end;
end;
```

Update 1:

```
// this code works fine
procedure TFormTest.btnAppActivateClick(Sender: TObject);
var
  sTitle, sKeys: string;
begin
    sTitle := '*WordPad';
    sKeys  := 'Hello{ENTER}World!';

    AppActivate(sTitle);
    SendKeys(PChar(sKeys), False);
end;
```

menu item handler (which invoked by hotkey HotKeyId_M):

```
procedure TFormMain.mnPasteLoginClick(Sender: TObject);
begin
  SendKeys('Hello{ENTER}World!', False);
end;
```

hotkeys:

```
HotKeyId_L: Integer;
HotKeyId_M: Integer;
```

initialization of hotkeys:

```
HotKeyId_L := GlobalAddAtom('HotKeyL');
RegisterHotKey(Handle, HotKeyId_L, MOD_CONTROL + MOD_ALT, Byte('L'));
HotKeyId_M := GlobalAddAtom('HotKeyM');
RegisterHotKey(Handle, HotKeyId_L, MOD_CONTROL + MOD_ALT, Byte('M'));
```

Update 2: (full code for test)

```
unit Unit2;

interface

uses
  Windows, Messages, SysUtils, Classes, Graphics, Controls, Forms, Dialogs,
  StdCtrls, Menus;

type
  TForm2 = class(TForm)
    btnActivate: TButton;
    popPopup: TPopupMenu;
    Paste1: TMenuItem;
    procedure btnActivateClick(Sender: TObject);
    procedure Paste1Click(Sender: TObject);
    procedure FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
    procedure FormDestroy(Sender: TObject);
  private
    HotKeyId_L: Integer;
    HotKeyId_M: Integer;
    procedure wm_hotkeyhandler(var Msg: TWMHotkey); message WM_HOTKEY;
  public
    { Public declarations }
  end;

var
  Form2: TForm2;

implementation

{$R *.DFM}

type
  TCompareDirection = (cdHead, cdTail, cdNone);

  TWindowObj = class(TObject)
  private
    targetTitle : PChar;
    compareLength: Integer;
    FCompareDirection: TCompareDirection;
    FWindowHandle: THandle;
  public
    constructor Create;
    destructor Destroy; override;
    function Equal(ATitle: PChar): Boolean;
    function SetTitle(const Title: string ): Boolean;
    property WindowHandle: THandle read FWindowHandle write FWindowHandle;
  end;

function EnumWindowsProc(hWnd: HWND; lParam: LPARAM):Bool; export; stdcall;
var
  WinObj: TWindowObj;
  aWndName: array[0..MAX_PATH] of Char;
begin
  Result := True;
  WinObj := TWindowObj(lParam);
  GetWindowText(hWnd, aWndName, MAX_PATH);
  if WinObj.Equal(aWndName) then begin
    WinObj.WindowHandle := hWnd;
    Result := False; // Stop Enumerate
  end;
end;

function GetWindowHandleByTitle(const Title: string): THandle;
var
  WinObj: TWindowObj;
begin
  Result := 0;
  WinObj := TWindowObj.Create;
  try
    if WinObj.SetTitle(Title) then begin
      EnumWindows(@EnumWindowsProc, Integer(WinObj));
      Result := WinObj.WindowHandle;
    end;
  finally
    WinObj.Free;
  end;
end;

function AppActivate(const Title: string ): Boolean;
var
  hWnd: THandle;
begin
  hWnd := GetWindowHandleByTitle(Title);
  Result := (hWnd > 0);
  if Result then begin
    SendMessage(hWnd, WM_SYSCOMMAND, SC_HOTKEY, hWnd);
    SendMessage(hWnd, WM_SYSCOMMAND, SC_RESTORE, hWnd);
    SetForegroundWindow(hWnd);
  end;
end;


constructor TWindowObj.Create;
begin
  TargetTitle := nil;
  FWindowHandle := 0;
end;

destructor TWindowObj.Destroy;
begin
  inherited Destroy;
  if Assigned(TargetTitle) then
    StrDispose(TargetTitle) ;
end;

function TWindowObj.Equal(ATitle: PChar): Boolean;
var
  p : Pchar;
  stringLength : integer;
begin
  Result := False;
  if (TargetTitle = nil) then
    Exit;
  case FCompareDirection of
    cdHead: begin
              if StrLIComp(ATitle, TargetTitle, compareLength) = 0 then
                Result := True;
            end;
    cdTail: begin
              stringLength := StrLen(ATitle);
              p := @ATitle[stringLength - compareLength];
              if (StrLIComp(p, Targettitle, compareLength) = 0) then
                Result := True;
            end;
    cdNone: begin
              Result := True;
            end;
  end;
end;


function TWindowObj.SetTitle(const Title: string ): Boolean;
var
  pTitle, p: PChar;
begin
  Result := False;
  pTitle := StrAlloc(Length(Title) + 1);
  StrPCopy(pTitle, Title);
  p := StrScan(pTitle, '*');
  if Assigned(p) then begin
    if StrLen(pTitle) = 1 then begin  {full matching }
      FCompareDirection := cdNone;
      compareLength := 0;
      TargetTitle := nil;
      StrDispose(pTitle);
    end
    else
    if (p = pTitle) then begin   {tail matching }
      Inc(p);
      if StrScan(p, '*') <> nil then begin
         {MessageDlg( 'Please 1 wild char ', mtError, [mbOK],0 ); }
         StrDispose( pTitle);
         TargetTitle := nil;
         FCompareDirection := cdNone;
         Comparelength := 0;
         exit;
      end;
      FCompareDirection := cdTail;
      CompareLength := StrLen(PTitle) - 1;
      TargetTitle := StrAlloc(StrLen(p) + 1 );
      StrCopy(targetTitle, p);
      StrDispose(PTitle);
    end
    else begin
      p^ := #0;
      FCompareDirection := cdHead;
      CompareLength := Strlen( pTitle );
      Targettitle := pTitle;
    end;
   end
   else begin
     FCompareDirection := cdHead;
     compareLength := Strlen( pTitle );
     TargetTitle := pTitle;
   end;
  Result := True;
end;


//========================================
// SendKeys
//
// Converts a string of characters and key names to keyboard events and passes them to Windows.
//
// Example syntax:
// SendKeys('abc123{left}{left}{left}def{end}456{left 6}ghi{end}789', True);

function SendKeys(SendStr: PChar; Wait: Boolean): Boolean;
type
  WBytes = array[0..pred(SizeOf(Word))] of Byte;
  TSendKey = record
    Name : ShortString;
    VKey : Byte;
  end;

const
  // Array of keys that SendKeys recognizes.
  // If you add to this list, you must be sure to keep it sorted alphabetically
  // by Name because a binary search routine is used to scan it.}

  MaxSendKeyRecs = 41;
  SendKeyRecs : array[1..MaxSendKeyRecs] of TSendKey = (
   (Name:'BACKSPACE';       VKey:VK_BACK),
   (Name:'BKSP';            VKey:VK_BACK),
   (Name:'BREAK';           VKey:VK_CANCEL),
   (Name:'BS';              VKey:VK_BACK),
   (Name:'CAPSLOCK';        VKey:VK_CAPITAL),
   (Name:'CLEAR';           VKey:VK_CLEAR),
   (Name:'DEL';             VKey:VK_DELETE),
   (Name:'DELETE';          VKey:VK_DELETE),
   (Name:'DOWN';            VKey:VK_DOWN),
   (Name:'END';             VKey:VK_END),
   (Name:'ENTER';           VKey:VK_RETURN),
   (Name:'ESC';             VKey:VK_ESCAPE),
   (Name:'ESCAPE';          VKey:VK_ESCAPE),
   (Name:'F1';              VKey:VK_F1),
   (Name:'F10';             VKey:VK_F10),
   (Name:'F11';             VKey:VK_F11),
   (Name:'F12';             VKey:VK_F12),
   (Name:'F13';             VKey:VK_F13),
   (Name:'F14';             VKey:VK_F14),
   (Name:'F15';             VKey:VK_F15),
   (Name:'F16';             VKey:VK_F16),
   (Name:'F2';              VKey:VK_F2),
   (Name:'F3';              VKey:VK_F3),
   (Name:'F4';              VKey:VK_F4),
   (Name:'F5';              VKey:VK_F5),
   (Name:'F6';              VKey:VK_F6),
   (Name:'F7';              VKey:VK_F7),
   (Name:'F8';              VKey:VK_F8),
   (Name:'F9';              VKey:VK_F9),
   (Name:'HELP';            VKey:VK_HELP),
   (Name:'HOME';            VKey:VK_HOME),
   (Name:'INS';             VKey:VK_INSERT),
   (Name:'LEFT';            VKey:VK_LEFT),
   (Name:'NUMLOCK';         VKey:VK_NUMLOCK),
   (Name:'PGDN';            VKey:VK_NEXT),
   (Name:'PGUP';            VKey:VK_PRIOR),
   (Name:'PRTSC';           VKey:VK_PRINT),
   (Name:'RIGHT';           VKey:VK_RIGHT),
   (Name:'SCROLLLOCK';      VKey:VK_SCROLL),
   (Name:'TAB';             VKey:VK_TAB),
   (Name:'UP';              VKey:VK_UP)
  );

  {Extra VK constants missing from Delphi's Windows API interface}
  VK_NULL=0;
  VK_SemiColon=186;
  VK_Equal=187;
  VK_Comma=188;
  VK_Minus=189;
  VK_Period=190;
  VK_Slash=191;
  VK_BackQuote=192;
  VK_LeftBracket=219;
  VK_BackSlash=220;
  VK_RightBracket=221;
  VK_Quote=222;
  VK_Last=VK_Quote;

  ExtendedVKeys : set of byte =
  [VK_Up,
   VK_Down,
   VK_Left,
   VK_Right,
   VK_Home,
   VK_End,
   VK_Prior,  {PgUp}
   VK_Next,   {PgDn}
   VK_Insert,
   VK_Delete];

const
  INVALIDKEY = $FFFF {Unsigned -1};
  VKKEYSCANSHIFTON = $01;
  VKKEYSCANCTRLON = $02;
  VKKEYSCANALTON = $04;
  UNITNAME = 'SendKeys';
var
  UsingParens, ShiftDown, ControlDown, AltDown, FoundClose : Boolean;
  PosSpace : Byte;
  I, L : Integer;
  NumTimes, MKey : Word;
  KeyString : String[20];

  procedure DisplayMessage(Msg: PChar);
  begin
    MessageBox(0, Msg, UNITNAME, 0);
  end;

  function BitSet(BitTable, BitMask: Byte): Boolean;
  begin
    Result := ByteBool(BitTable and BitMask);
  end;

  procedure SetBit(var BitTable : Byte; BitMask : Byte);
  begin
    BitTable:=BitTable or Bitmask;
  end;

  procedure KeyboardEvent(VKey, ScanCode: Byte; Flags: DWORD);
  var
    KeyboardMsg : TMsg;
  begin
    keybd_event(VKey, ScanCode, Flags, 0);
    if Wait then
      while PeekMessage(KeyboardMsg, 0, WM_KEYFIRST, WM_KEYLAST, PM_REMOVE) do begin
        TranslateMessage(KeyboardMsg);
        DispatchMessage(KeyboardMsg);
      end;
  end;

  procedure SendKeyDown(VKey: Byte; NumTimes: Word; GenUpMsg: Boolean);
  var
    Cnt: Word;
    ScanCode: Byte;
    NumState: Boolean;
    KeyBoardState: TKeyboardState;
  begin
    if (VKey = VK_NUMLOCK) then begin
      NumState := ByteBool(GetKeyState(VK_NUMLOCK) and 1);
      GetKeyBoardState(KeyBoardState);
      if NumState then
        KeyBoardState[VK_NUMLOCK] := (KeyBoardState[VK_NUMLOCK] and not 1)
      else
        KeyBoardState[VK_NUMLOCK] := (KeyBoardState[VK_NUMLOCK] or 1);
      SetKeyBoardState(KeyBoardState);
      Exit;
    end;

    ScanCode := Lo(MapVirtualKey(VKey, 0));
    for Cnt := 1 to NumTimes do
      if (VKey in ExtendedVKeys) then begin
        KeyboardEvent(VKey, ScanCode, KEYEVENTF_EXTENDEDKEY);
        if GenUpMsg then
          KeyboardEvent(VKey, ScanCode, KEYEVENTF_EXTENDEDKEY or KEYEVENTF_KEYUP)
      end
      else begin
        KeyboardEvent(VKey, ScanCode, 0);
        if GenUpMsg then
          KeyboardEvent(VKey, ScanCode, KEYEVENTF_KEYUP);
      end;
  end;

  procedure SendKeyUp(VKey: Byte);
  var
    ScanCode : Byte;
  begin
    ScanCode := Lo(MapVirtualKey(VKey, 0));
    if (VKey in ExtendedVKeys)then
      KeyboardEvent(VKey, ScanCode, KEYEVENTF_EXTENDEDKEY and KEYEVENTF_KEYUP)
    else
      KeyboardEvent(VKey, ScanCode, KEYEVENTF_KEYUP);
  end;

  procedure SendKey(MKey: Word; NumTimes: Word; GenDownMsg: Boolean);
  begin
    if BitSet(Hi(MKey), VKKEYSCANSHIFTON) then  SendKeyDown(VK_SHIFT, 1, False);
    if BitSet(Hi(MKey), VKKEYSCANCTRLON)  then  SendKeyDown(VK_CONTROL, 1, False);
    if BitSet(Hi(MKey), VKKEYSCANALTON)   then  SendKeyDown(VK_MENU, 1, False);
    SendKeyDown(Lo(MKey), NumTimes, GenDownMsg);
    if BitSet(Hi(MKey), VKKEYSCANSHIFTON) then  SendKeyUp(VK_SHIFT);
    if BitSet(Hi(MKey), VKKEYSCANCTRLON)  then  SendKeyUp(VK_CONTROL);
    if BitSet(Hi(MKey), VKKEYSCANALTON)   then  SendKeyUp(VK_MENU);
  end;

  // Implements a simple binary search to locate special key name strings
  function StringToVKey(KeyString: ShortString): Word;
  var
    Found, Collided : Boolean;
    Bottom, Top, Middle : Byte;
  begin
    Result := INVALIDKEY;
    Bottom := 1;
    Top := MaxSendKeyRecs;
    Found := False;
    Middle := (Bottom + Top) div 2;
    repeat
      Collided:=((Bottom=Middle) or (Top=Middle));
      if (KeyString=SendKeyRecs[Middle].Name) then begin
         Found:=True;
         Result:=SendKeyRecs[Middle].VKey;
      end
      else begin
        if (KeyString>SendKeyRecs[Middle].Name) then
          Bottom:=Middle
        else
          Top:=Middle;
        Middle:=(Succ(Bottom+Top)) div 2;
      end;
    until (Found or Collided);
    if (Result = INVALIDKEY) then
      DisplayMessage('Invalid Key Name');
  end;

  procedure PopUpShiftKeys;
  begin
    if (not UsingParens) then begin
      if ShiftDown then   SendKeyUp(VK_SHIFT);
      if ControlDown then SendKeyUp(VK_CONTROL);
      if AltDown then     SendKeyUp(VK_MENU);
      ShiftDown   := False;
      ControlDown := False;
      AltDown     := False;
    end;
  end;

var
  AllocationSize : integer;
begin
  AllocationSize := MaxInt;
  Result := False;
  UsingParens := False;
  ShiftDown   := False;
  ControlDown := False;
  AltDown     := False;
  I := 0;
  L := StrLen(SendStr);
  if (L > AllocationSize) then
    L := AllocationSize;
  if (L = 0) then
    Exit;

  while (I < L) do begin
    case SendStr[I] of
    '(': begin
           UsingParens := True;
           Inc(I);
         end;
    ')': begin
           UsingParens := False;
           PopUpShiftKeys;
           Inc(I);
         end;
    '%': begin
            AltDown := True;
            SendKeyDown(VK_MENU, 1, False);
            Inc(I);
         end;
    '+':  begin
            ShiftDown := True;
            SendKeyDown(VK_SHIFT, 1, False);
            Inc(I);
          end;
    '^':  begin
            ControlDown := True;
            SendKeyDown(VK_CONTROL, 1, False);
            Inc(I);
          end;
    '{':  begin
            NumTimes := 1;
            if (SendStr[Succ(I)] = '{') then begin
              MKey := VK_LEFTBRACKET;
              SetBit(WBytes(MKey)[1], VKKEYSCANSHIFTON);
              SendKey(MKey, 1, True);
              PopUpShiftKeys;
              Inc(I, 3);
              Continue;
            end;
            KeyString := '';
            FoundClose := False;
            while (I <= L) do begin
              Inc(I);
              if (SendStr[I] = '}') then begin
                FoundClose := True;
                Inc(I);
                Break;
              end;
              KeyString := KeyString + Upcase(SendStr[I]);
            end;
            if Not FoundClose then begin
              DisplayMessage('No Close');
              Exit;
            end;
            if (SendStr[I] = '}') then begin
              MKey := VK_RIGHTBRACKET;
              SetBit(Wbytes(MKey)[1], VKKEYSCANSHIFTON);
              SendKey(MKey, 1, True);
              PopUpShiftKeys;
              Inc(I);
              Continue;
            end;
            PosSpace:=Pos(' ', KeyString);
            if (PosSpace <> 0) then begin
              NumTimes := StrToInt(Copy(KeyString, Succ(PosSpace), Length(KeyString) - PosSpace));
              KeyString := Copy(KeyString, 1, Pred(PosSpace));
            end;
            If (Length(KeyString)=1) then
              MKey := vkKeyScan(KeyString[1])
            else
              MKey := StringToVKey(KeyString);
            If (MKey <> INVALIDKEY) then begin
              SendKey(MKey, NumTimes, True);
              PopUpShiftKeys;
              Continue;
            end;
          end;
    '~':  begin
            SendKeyDown(VK_RETURN, 1, True);
            PopUpShiftKeys;
            Inc(I);
          end;
    else
      MKey := vkKeyScan(SendStr[I]);
      if (MKey <> INVALIDKEY) then begin
        SendKey(MKey, 1, True);
        PopUpShiftKeys;
      end
      else
        DisplayMessage('Invalid KeyName');
      Inc(I);
    end;
  end;
  Result := True;
  PopUpShiftKeys;
end;


procedure TForm2.btnActivateClick(Sender: TObject);
var
  sTitle, sKeys: string;
begin
  sTitle :=  '*WordPad';
  sKeys  := 'Hello{ENTER}World!';

  AppActivate(sTitle);
  SendKeys(PChar(sKeys), False);
end;

procedure TForm2.Paste1Click(Sender: TObject);
begin
  SendKeys('Hello{ENTER}World!', False);
end;

procedure TForm2.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
begin
  HotKeyId_L := GlobalAddAtom('HotKeyP');
  RegisterHotKey(Handle, HotKeyId_L, MOD_CONTROL or MOD_ALT, Byte('L'));
  HotKeyId_M := GlobalAddAtom('HotKeyM');
  RegisterHotKey(Handle, HotKeyId_M, MOD_CONTROL or MOD_ALT, Byte('M'));
end;

procedure TForm2.FormDestroy(Sender: TObject);
begin
  UnregisterHotKey(Handle, HotKeyId_L);
  GlobalDeleteAtom(HotKeyId_L);
end;

procedure TForm2.wm_hotkeyhandler(var Msg: TWMHotkey);
var
  Pt: TPoint;
begin
  inherited;
  if (Msg.HotKey = HotKeyId_L) then SendKeys('Hello{ENTER}World!', False);
  if (Msg.HotKey = HotKeyId_M) then begin
                                      GetCursorPos(Pt);
                                      popPopup.Popup(Pt.x, Pt.y);
                                    end;
end;

end.
```

Comment: We can't see you calling `AppActivate`, and we don't know how `AppActivate` and `SendKeys` are implemented. Please supply SSCCE in order for us to know what your code is.

Comment: Added content of AppActivate and SendKeys, AppActivate used from OnClick button for test, real usage - pasting any data to active application using hotkey

Comment: We still cannot see any evidence that you called `AppActivate`. We still don't have an SSCCE. If there was an SSCCE, I could paste it into my compiler and be running your code instantly. Then I could debug it and have an answer rapidly. As it stands, I cannot do anything to help you.

Comment: Added usage and creation of hotkeys

Comment: Thanks for the updates. I appreciate the effort. But why can't we have an SSCCE?

Comment: One minute, will create it, this is very big application

Comment: Thanks again for your efforts.

Comment: Update 2 contain Unit code for test

Comment: Yeah, that's kind of weird isn't it!

Comment: Indeed interesting. Tested to see if SendInput fails similarly. It does. Fire a timer to synthesize your input, or post a message to your form or something similar, if you cannot resolve this I mean..

Comment: @SertacAkyuz I tried posting a message without luck. I cannot make any sense of this.

Comment: @David - Yeah, me neither. SendInput doesn't report fail. While debugging, if I trace, keys are written to the editor. BTW timer fails too (writes some weird, arbitrary characters/text or calls some command, after I press ctrl+alt+L).

Comment: I'm having *slightly* better results when wait parameter is true..

Comment: The minimum interval for the timer for correct keys to be sent is about 250ms here on my computer. Not a reliable solution.. I wonder what is being corrupted when you don't delay sending keys..

Comment: Yes, have this procedures several years, but can't make it valid from hotkey handler